# PHPStorm: XDebug stops working after a while

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a PHP/Backbone.js application.  I use PHP Storm and X Debug to debug.  The app has a lot of sycnronous and asyc call to the PHP code.  My problem is that my debug will often just quit working.  Even worst, it will halt the running code.  If the debugger is off, everything runs fine.  If I place a break point very early on in the code, it will work and then, at some some point just quit.

Is this an XDebug issue or Php Storm?  Oh, and there are not errors thrown or recorded.  Also, I've tried debugging in Chrome and Firefox.  Same problem.

> Log opened at 2016-01-30 18:26:30 I: Connecting to configured
>   address/port: localhost:9000. I: Connected to client. :-)
>   ->
>
> <- feature_set -i 0 -n show_hidden -v 1
>   ->
>
> <- feature_set -i 1 -n max_depth -v 1
>   ->
>
> <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 100
>   ->
>
> <- status -i 3
>   ->
>
> <- step_into -i 4
>   ->
>
> <- eval -i 5 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
>   ->
>
> <- eval -i 6 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
>   ->
>
> <- eval -i 7 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
>   ->
>
> <- eval -i 8 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
>   ->
>
> <- eval -i 9 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
>   ->
>
> <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f
>   file://C:/wamp/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/classes/api/mysubfolder/MyClass.php
>   -n 264
>   ->
>
> <- stack_get -i 11
>   ->
>
> <- run -i 12
>   ->
>
> <- run -i 13 Log closed at 2016-01-30 18:26:31

Comment: Try to increase the maximum of simultatneous connections (prefs->Languages>PHP>Debug ) especially with async stuff, ajax and web services.

Comment: Also, if it helps, I will add the Xdbug log

Comment: are you hitting memory limits?

Comment: Thanks for the reposne, Yves.  I'm not sure what version you are using.  For me, I don't see preferences.  But, if I go File->settings-PHP->debug, I have these settings:  Safe Eval (checked), Pass required config...(checked), Ignore External Connections through...(unchecked).  Then, under that is Max simultaneous connections.  It was a t 1.  I moved it to 10.  Still no good.

Comment: Not sure about reaching memory limits.  I don't see any issues when I run task manager.  Also, there are no errors in PHP or Apacher error log, or the Xdbug error log.  Is there another way to check?

Comment: Take that back.  I upped it to 50 and restarted WAMP.  That did it!  Thanks.  If you add this as a response, Ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase the maximum of simultatneous connections (prefs->Languages>PHP>Debug ) especially with async stuff, ajax and web services. (I run phhStorm 10.0.3 on a mac, similar type of stack) , I upped it to 20.